# Adjacency list representation of graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

In an algorithms course from Stanford, the professor listed the following ingredients for the adjacency list representation of graphs:

1. Array or List of Vertices
2. Array or List of Edges
3. Each vertex in the List of Vertices points to the edges incident on it.
4. Each edge in the List of Edges points to its edgepoints.

Does this correspond to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)? The object oriented incidence list structure suggested by Goodrich and Tamassia has special classes of vertex objects and edge objects?

Is this representation same as "incidence list"  representation of graphs? If yes, why are "adjacency list" and "incidence list"  considered separated in [this article](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_data_structures#Incidence_List)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the author of the article would call that structure an incidence list, since nodes link to other nodes via edges rather than directly. The incidence list/adjacency list distinction is nonstandard and IMHO not terribly useful because both structures have similar performance characteristics and because it's not clear that the distinction is well-founded if one strips away the list ADT.

Comment: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-that-job-at-google.html . There are three basic ways to represent a graph in memory (objects and pointers, matrix, and adjacency list), and you should familiarize yourself with each representation and its pros and cons. Here also the author speaks about the three different representations. Don't you think basically there are only two representations?

Comment: @vkaul11 There are many representations, but the most useful distinction is between adjacency matrices and lists. Seemingly the only distinction between Yegge's "objects and pointers" and "adjacency list" is how things are structured in an object-oriented program.

Comment: I agree as in Tim Roughgarden's class he does not really distinguish between the lists and objects and pointers.